# One word verb for accidentally painting outside the lines

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a one word verb for accidentally painting outside of a given outline or painting the top of your lip with the lipstick without intending to? I suppose if there is one the same should be used for both situations.

Comment: "Screwup" would probably work.

Comment: [***smudge***](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/smudge) would probably work better.

Comment: Slip… mistake… tragedy, sometimes